# Modifying column label for regression tables

Tags: r, label, regression, lm

I would like to relabel variables in a R data.frame, say for example I have `data$X` and `data$Y`, where Y is height and X is gender. I then run a linear regression:

```
reg <- lm(Y ~ X, data)
```

Then when I run `summary(reg)`, the table should show Y and X as height and gender. The equivalent command in STATA would be:

```
label variable y  "Height"
```

Sorry for this simple question, but after quite some searching, I didn't manage to find an answer. Thanks!

Comment: You can rename the columns and do the lm or may modify the call i.e. `reg$call$formula <- quote(height ~ gender)`

Comment: Check the structure, it is pretty complex object, `str(reg)` and `str(summary(reg))`. It is possible to look for all Xs and Ys and replace them with "labels" manually. But it is far more easier to rename the data columns before calling lm.